# Need advise for porting linux script to Win command line

Tags: windows, linux, bash

I am creating app(script) that is used similar to RSS reader for specific webpage that doesn't have RSS.

So my app downloads that html page in defined intervals, checks new items and parses them into messages that are sent over network.

But my app prototype is written in Bash (Linux is my primary OS), and I was asked that this app will be needed on Windows also - luckily WinXP 32bit only.

So I am deciding how rewrite it easily and without testing various scripting languages and technologies.

Currently my app is working with Bash, and calls for unix utilities like sed, wget and curl. I checked that these utilities are for win32 also.

So my question is about Windows commandline capabilities compared to linux bash. Does wincmd have similar capabilities like bash? In e.g. manipulating strings, cycles or something that might be a problem?

I also found Cygwin, but don't know if it works reliable and this is important in this case of app.

Comment: Why not use MSYS?  It has bash and several other commonly used utilities and will save you the trouble of porting.  Plus it's has no dependencies and is easy to distribute (unlike Cygwin) -- you could [literally pack it in a zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/).

Comment: This would be a lot easier to just write in python

Comment: Why did you choose to use Bash with various command line utilities (sed, etc.) rather than a script language and environment such as python, php, ruby, or perl?

Comment: Because I have no knowledge of any scripting languages yet. I wanted to be run without installing of any external components (I see this is probably not possible easily).In Bash i had my app working in about 10 minutes.
Maybe its good the right time to start learning some of these languages. Any recommendations for sth similar to C++/Bash ? :)

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @Rufflewind Could you write an answer with your MSYS recommendation ?

Comment: I would recommend Python because it's used widely even on Windows platforms.  It still requires an installation but it's very easy to do.  The language itself is IMHO by far one of the easiest to learn.  The tricky part is writing Python that's portable to multiple versions but portability is a problem in every language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows cmd is far more limited than bash. For example, 'if', 'for' and 'goto' are the only flow of control functions, and the versions provided by cmd are fare more limited than the ones in bash. You might eventually be able to write a Windows cmd shell script that duplicates the functionality of a complex bash script, but  it will take you ages, and you won't enjoy it. If you need to port a complex script, try using [Microsoft Windows Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) instead. It programming model is very different from bash, so it will need a complete re-write, but it has quite good capabilities.

If you want to stick to bash, then [MinGw](http://www.mingw.org) and [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) are your only choices. Both have been around for years and are quite reliable, but of course will require a separate and fairly extensive install process for the folks using your script

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was afraid of...
Problem is that there are much less information about programming in wincmd than programming in bash.
I will try Cygwin, but not sure if it wouldn't be better to learn some other scripting language or try to write my app in C++ (always had troubles with calling external binaries from C and parsing their output).

Comment: User @rufflewind mentions a *msys* tool that requires no configuration, just unzip a file.

Comment: MSYS is part of MinGW.  If you don't need the actual compiler from MinGW, then MSYS is all you need.  It's basically a zip file of basic Unix tools, including bash, sed, etc.

Comment: Also if you *do* need the compiler, then I would recommend Mingw-w64 over regular Mingw as it has more features and is more maintained.